# OpenWrt router acting just as a switch with another WAN from wifi client

Tags: subnet, wan, openwrt, 3g

I have here this networking problem I can't figure out.
My situation is following:

- ADSL cable connection to WAN, provider's router/modem (some Zyxel), DHCP running, original firmware, not possible to use OpenWRT
- My TP-Link WR1043ND router, OpenWRT installed
- T-Mobile 3G USB Wireless modem - another internet connection, there is not much configuration possible

What I need is one subnet for all devices connected to the network. 
So, the provider's Zyxel router will run a DHCP server and all devices gets assigned IP from there.
Thus, my TP-Link router has disabled DHCP.
This is not the problem yet, this all works for me.

What I need is that for few computers in the network, I want to use the T-Mobile connection for access to the internet. But still all computers have to be in the same subnet.
All devices need to see each other.

Is that even possible?

The way is through client mode I guess. I was thinking that the T-Mobile WiFi could be client to the TP-Link router, with assigned local IP, so maybe for the computer where I want to use the T-Mobile connection, I could just use this IP as a gateway…but this idea is wrong, or I have something else wrong…because it doesn't work.

Comment: So both WAN connections (ADSL and TMobile 3G) are connected to the TP-Link and you want the TP Link to not do any routing at all?

Comment: I'd be fine with anything, but I need to be able setup different gateway for some computers in the network, that's the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Just number all devices inside the same subnet. For devices the use the T-mobile device to get Internet access, use a statically configured default route that points to the T-mobile device.

Comment: I'm trying for something like this, but no luck :( I'll put here more details about what exactly I'm trying, maybe you can see the problem.